# Unable to remove margin bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a gap just below my first pre tag I can not remove it.

I have tried

```
pre {
    margin: 0 0 0;
}
```

And

```
pre {
    margin: 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

But still shows

[image]

> **Question:** How is it possible to correctly remove the margin or padding
>   just below the first pre?

***Note: just found out something to do with nl2br on controller function below***

I use codeigniter and ajax to generate the preview.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

pre {
    display: block;
    padding: 9.5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

hr {
    background-color: #dedede !important;
    height: 1px !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('question/preview');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            title: $('#title').val(), 
            question: $('#question').val(),
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
                $('#preview').html(response.question);
                $('#preview pre br').remove();
                var str = $('#preview pre').html();
                $('#preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
                $('pre').each(function(i, block) {
                    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                });
            } else {

            }
        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();  
});
</script>
```

Function

```
public function preview() {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'question' => '');

    if ($_POST) {

        $data['question'] = nl2br($this->input->post('question'));

        $data['success'] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

FULL HTML

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('question/create', array('id' => 'question_create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form'));?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title"></h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Title</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Question</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<textarea name="question" id="question"  class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2"></label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="preview-question" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Clear Textarea</button>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('question/preview');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            title: $('#title').val(), 
            question: $('#question').val(),
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
                $('#preview').html(response.question);
                $('#preview pre br').remove();
                var str = $('#preview pre').html();
                $('#preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));
                $('#preview pre').each(function(i, block) {
                    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                });
            } else {

            }
        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();  
});
</script>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: It has something to do with the nl2br on controller function

Comment: Can you please give me the HTML of the element in your browser?

Comment: @djl is I have noted it something to do with the nl2br on controller

Comment: ok, in that case check if there is no 'invisible' breaks in your code

Comment: Thanks for that tip that worked I added a jquery replace in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think if you format your HTML like this, you can manage the margins of a `pre` element. You have to apply the 'box' styles of color and backgroud e.g. to the `.highlight` class and the other styles to the `pre`.

The `code` element is optional if you use the same 'code recognizer' as bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<figure class="highlight">
  <pre>
    <!--<code class="language-html" data-lang="html">-->
    <!-- your code here -->
    <!--</code>-->
  </pre>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    padding: 9px 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0; /* no margin-bottom */        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First i think you should use

pre {

```
margin: 0 0 0 0  !important;
```

}
instead of

pre {

```
margin: 0 0 0   !important;
```

}
Let me know if that helps

Comment: No sorry does not

Answer (score 0):

Add clear into the pre tag

```
pre {
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @djl suggestion I have found out i needed to add `replace('\n', '')` to my script below to remove invisible line breaks

All working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('question/preview');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            title: $('#title').val(), 
            question: $('#question').val(),
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
                $('#preview').html(response.question);
                $('#preview pre br').remove();
                var str = $('#preview pre').html();
                $('#preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace('\n', ''));
                $('#preview pre').each(function(i, block) {
                    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                });
            } else {

            }
        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();  
});
</script>
```